# Can NuGet Browse for Packages Whose Assemblies Define a Particular Namespace?

Tags: .net, namespaces, nuget-package

I often find myself struggling to identify which package(s) define a particular namespace.

Microsoft Documentation will identify the namespace, but not the NuGet package.

Perhaps this problem is too hard for NuGet; but Microsoft might at least provide some sort of index.

Is there a practical approach that will help determine which packages satisfy an undefined namespace reference?

Comment: ReSharper has a function for attempting to find a missing NuGet package.

Comment: Good to know Micky.  Can you provide a little more detail on how to get at this feature?
Thanks

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Finding_Exploring_and_Installing_NuGet_Packages.html